# Create Dynamic fileupload api in php

Tags: php, api, file-upload

I am working on file upload api in php. For Now I just create this simple php which will upload the file from an html page to server. But in this code the fileupload control's name is fixed so I pass that name in my php code for upload the file. But I want to create this api for third party. If anybody ask for api then I will give link of my api and they will consume it. Now anybody please help me to convert this into dynamic

Here is the html code

```
<html>
<head>
 </head>
 <body>

 <h2>Upload Image </h2>
<form action="http://mvcangularworld.com/api.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<input type="file" name="filename" value="" />
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload File"  />
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

and here is my php code for api.php

```
<?php

// Path to move uploaded files
$target_path = 'images/';


$response = array();


$file_upload_url = $target_path;
$filename = $_POST['filename']; 
 if (isset($_FILES['filename']['name'])) 
{
    $target_path = $target_path . basename($_FILES['filename']['name']);
    // reading other post parameters
    echo $_FILES['filename']['name']."<br />";
    echo $_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']."<br />";

    $response['file_name'] = basename($_FILES['filename']['name']);

    try 
    {
        // Throws exception incase file is not being moved
        if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) 
        {
            // make error flag true
            $response['error'] = true;
            $response['message'] = 'Could not move the file!';
        }

        // File successfully uploaded
         //echo $file_upload_url . basename($_FILES['filename']['name']);
        $response['message'] = 'File uploaded successfully!';
        $response['error'] = false;
        $response['file_path'] = $file_upload_url . basename($_FILES['filename']['name']);
    } 
    catch (Exception $e) 
    {
        // Exception occurred. Make error flag true
        $response['error'] = true;
        $response['message'] = $e->getMessage();
    }
} 
//else 
//{ 
    // File parameter is missing
 /*    $response['error'] = true;
    $response['message'] = 'Not received any file';
} */

// Echo final json response to client
echo

 json_encode($response, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
?>
```

here is the api link

http://mvcangularworld.com/api.php

Please help me to make this api dynamic

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution can be, add a hidden field which have name of file field like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="fileFieldName" value="filename" />
```

and on server side:

```
$fileFieldName = $_POST['fileFieldName'];
move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$fileFieldName]['tmp_name']
```

Comment: I just want to make my api dynamic so that if I give it to any body that person can consume that according this requirement. I donot want to tell the client to add a hidden field in your html

Comment: @Azadchouhan It is not wrong to do so. Most CSRF APIs do ask users to implement hidden fields.

Comment: actually I have to give this to a andriod developer so that he can upload image to my server using his anrdiod app

Comment: So you can mention in your api documents: Either Name of file field should be "filename" or take a hidden field named "fileFieldName" and value "filename".